# Is there a shorter way to change username, home directory and move files at the same time

Tags: users, sudo

I wanted to use and have tried

```
sudo usermod durrantm_test -mdl durrantm_test2
```

but I get

```
Usage: usermod [options] LOGIN
...
```

However

```
sudo usermod durrantm_test -l durrantm_test2 -md durrantm_test2
```

doesn't give an error but seems repetitive, can I shorten it?

Comment: This is a great question imo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
usrmodx() { sudo usermod "$1" -l "$2" -md "$2"; }
usrmodx durrantm_test durrantm_test2
```

But shouldn't it be,

```
sudo usermod -l new_name -md new_dir old_name
```

so

```
sudo usermod -l durrantm_test2 -md durrantm_test2 durrantm_test
```

and as a function,

```
moveuser() { sudo usermod -l "$2" -md "$2" "$1"; }
moveuser durrantm_test durrantm_test2
```

or am I missing something?

This assumes you're using a shell which supports functions (e.g. bash), and avoids aliases because you can't use positional variables.

Comment: What sort of shell are you using that allows positional parameters (`$1`, `$2`, ...) in aliases?

Comment: make believe shell - apologies, I'll correct.

Comment: Note that you may also need to rename crontabs, mailboxes, possible entries in /etc/aliases and wherever the old name might have been referenced.

Comment: The original query is about a way to shorten a repetitive command, not a way to successfully and completely migrate user names.