# How to change the username in Ubuntu 10.10?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, users

I want to change a username.
In the prompt, which says `abhishek@hello$`, I want to replace `abhishek` with `alok` (i.e. `alok@hello$`).  Is it possible to do that without reinstalling Ubuntu?

Comment: See also [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/40610/9537).

Answer (score 4):

You can change your username and move all files in your current home directory to your new home directory using

`usermod -l alok -md /home/alok abhishek`

Got the answer from another reply: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/40611/26851

Comment: Hi fotomonster, thanks for the reply. Is there any way to change the current home directory name?

Comment: The `-md /home/alok` part should have moved your old homedirectory already.

Comment: Just saw that there was a typo in the `usermod` line, so you home directory possibly hasn't been moved. Issuing `usermod -md /home/alok alok` should move the files in your home directory.

Comment: Hi fotomonster, thanks for your suggestion. I have tried but terminal displays the following message - usermod: user 'alok' does not exist. Is there a need to create first "alok" home directory or "alok" user account? if yes, can you suggest how to create it.

Comment: You need to modify the existing username first            #usermod -l login-name old-name